# "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found"

Tags: nativescript

First question here. I can't find a similar question for Nativescript (though I have found one for Ionic and Cordova).

I am getting this message when connected to an Android 6 device via livesync:

"No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin."

Can I install cordova plugins in a Nativescript project?

If so, how and how do I add the meta info needed in a Nativescript template?

Comment: Are you running a Cordova app in the background that spits out the message while you're looking at the NativeScript app? Kill all apps and try again, as there's no such thing being emitted from a NativeScript app.

Comment: No Cordova apps running, but oddly I have run livesync today after running a build and get no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running:

`tns build android`

This message seem to go away. Not really sure how that would make a difference, but hopefully that will help someone.